# How to refresh a viewcomponent asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

i have a view with 3 combo boxes that get their options from a database. when an option in one of them is selected, the others may have to be filtered. im making the call to my controller with ajax:

```
$(".dropFilter").on('change', function () {
var data = {
    'EventEmitter': $(this).attr("id"),
    'SelectedValue': $(this).val()
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../MyController/FilterCombos',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    },
    fail: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    },

});
});
```

the controller method being called is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult FilterCombos([FromBody]FilterComboRequest fcr)
    {
        switch (fcr.EventEmitter)
        {
            case "combo1-dropdown":
                return ViewComponent("MyViewComponent", new
                {
                    firstFilter = fcr.SelectedValue,
                    secondFilter = 0,
                    thirdFilter = fcr.SelectedValue
                });
            case "combo2-dropdown":
                return ViewComponent("MyViewComponent", new
                {
                    firstFilter = 0,
                    secondFilter = fcr.SelectedValue,
                    thirdFilter = 0
                });
        }

        return ViewComponent("MyViewComponent", new
        {
            firstFilter = 0,
            secondFilter = 0,
            thirdFilter = 0
        });
    }
```

my viewcomponent invokeAsync method is the following:

```
 public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int firstFilter,int secondFilter,int thirdFilter)
    {
        var mOpciones = new MOpciones();
        var lOpciones = new LOpciones(_config);
        lOpciones.fill(mOpciones,firstFilter,secondFilter,thirdFilter);
        return View(mOpciones);
    }
```

the combos are filled like so:

```
@Html.DropDownList("combo1",
                new SelectList(Model.First,"Id","Nombre"),
                "",
                new { @class = "col-6 form-control form-control-lg", 
                      @id="combo1-dropdown" })
```

when debugging, i see that mOpciones is being filled correctly in InvokeAsync, and Model.First has the right options in Default.cshtml, but the view on the browser never changes. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Feel drop-down values can be updated within Ajax call method in JS.

Example:

```
success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                            $("#Dropdown").append('<option value="'
                             + value.Value + '">'
                             + value.Value + '</option>');
                        });
```